# An unexpected error occurred: ant jar > /dev/null exited with 127 in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, ant

i using phongap to create android application. Whenever i run ./create it shows me error:

here is what in command i am running

```
./create /Users/nehulagrawal/Desktop/PhoneGapTestExample com.sometest.PhoneGapTest PhoneGapTest
```

And my path in .bash-profile is:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/nehulagrawal/Desktop/android-adt/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/nehulagrawal/Desktop/android-adt/sdk/tools
```

It was not taking the path so i edit  the "create" file and make it looks like

```
ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=/Users/nehulagrawal/Desktop/android-adt/sdk/tools/android}"
```

ERROR i am getting is:

```
./create: line 106: ant: command not found
An unexpected error occurred: ant jar > /dev/null exited with 127
Deleting project...
```

Dont know where the problem is it. Please any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `phonegap create`

Comment: Yes i tried and it worked. But its not generated in the way as expected. Like in the form of android project. With mainfest.xml, res folder and other.

Comment: you need to run `phonegap create` then `phonegap platform add android` and then `phonegap build` after that in the `platforms` folder you will see `android` in there you will find all of the items you just mentioned

Comment: Ok problem solved. That was a "ant" problem so i install "homebrew" and then install "ant" in Mac OS X thats the only way i find. And that worked now like charm.

Comment: Oh, yeah I had to do the same (install homebrew to install ant)

Comment: Still i must say, thank you for your concern. If could help you with anything, just drop me a line. nehul.agrawal is my skype name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

install ant using brew

Download and install Homebrew by executing following command in terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install Apache Ant via Homebrew by executing

```
brew install ant
```

Run the PhoneGap build again and it should successfully compile and install your Android app.

Comment: The Homebrew installer has moved! Please instead run:
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`